# Django adding basic search in navbar

Tags: django

In process of adding basic search bar for searching the menu titles in my menu list I am getting this error

```
    django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'title_icontains' into field. Choices are: id, menu_title, price, title_content
```

Do I have to make a model for the search??

my form view in basic.html looks like this

```
     <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0" action="/search/" method="get">
              <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" name="q" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
              <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit" value="Search">Search</button>
            </form>
```

my views.py

```
   from django.shortcuts import render
   from django.http import HttpResponse,Http404,HttpResponseRedirect,HttpResponseNotFound
   from resturant.models import Carousel
   from resturant.models import Menu
   from django.db.models import Q
   from django import forms

def search(request):
if 'q' in request.GET and request.GET['q']:
    q = request.GET['q']
    menu_item = Menu.objects.filter(title_icontains = q)
    return render(request, 'sources/search_results.html',{'menu_item':menu_item, 'query': q})

else:
    return HttpResponse('Please submit a search term.')
```

my search_results.html

```
{% if menu_item %}
    <p>Found {{ menu_item|length }} item{{ menu_item|pluralize }}.</p>
        <ul>
            {% for s in menu_item %}
            <li class="wow fadeInUp" data-wow-duration="300ms" data-wow-delay="300ms">
                <div class="item">
                    <div class="item-title">
                    <h2>{{ s.menu_title }}</h2>
                    <div class="border-bottom"></div>
                    <span>$ {{s.price}}</span>
                    </div>
                    <p>{{s.title_content}}</p>
                </div>
            </li>
            {% endfor %}
        </ul>
{% else %}
    <p>No Menu_Items matched your search criteria.</p>
{% endif %}
```

And my urls.py

```
    from django.conf.urls import url
    from . import views
    from django.contrib.auth.views import login

    urlpatterns =[ 
     url(r'^$', views.index , name= "index"),
     url(r'^menu/$', views.menu , name= "menu"),
     url(r'^check/$',views.check,name='check'),
     url(r'^search/$',views.search, name='search')

                   ]
```

Sorry for not posting menu models it looks like this

```
    class Menu(models.Model):
         menu_title = models.CharField(max_length = 100,)
         price = models.IntegerField()
         title_content = models.CharField(max_length = 500,)
```

Comment: please post menu's model

Comment: Sorry for that @Ykh I have now included the menu model plz help

Answer (score 0):

```
def search(request):
    if 'q' in request.GET and request.GET['q']:
        q = request.GET['q']
        menu_item = Menu.objects.filter(menu_title_icontains = q)
        return render(request, 'sources/search_results.html',{'menu_item':menu_item, 'query': q})

    else:
        return HttpResponse('Please submit a search term.')
```

change `menu_item = Menu.objects.filter(title_icontains = q)` to `menu_item = Menu.objects.filter(menu_title_icontains = q)`

Comment: Thanks for help. It works according to your modification but I got only my price and title_contains back not menu_title . I cant figure it why though. Thanks @Ykh

Comment: It looks like my menu title is hidden under the navigation bar any idea how to separate those two

Comment: can't help you with html question

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that there 2 underscore symbol between field name and "icontains":

```
menu_item = Menu.objects.filter(title__icontains = q)
```